# How do I prevent "_t" field from appearing when Upserting into MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have an application which makes Upserts into a MongoDB database, using the c# driver for MongoDB. When I call the `Update` function, I can't specify the type I want to update, and then a `_t` field is inserted with the type of the element.

Here's the code I use to upsert:

```
collection.Update(
    Query.EQ("key", item.Key),
    Update.Replace(item),
    UpdateFlags.Upsert
);
```

Here's the result:

[image: mongodbscreenshot]

This does not happen when I do the initial inserts, since I can specify the type.

How can I make Upserts without inserting the `_t` field?

[Edit] That's the code I use for inserting:

```
collection.InsertBatch(ItemType, items);
```

Comment: can you share the upsert code plz?

Comment: What do you mean by specifying the type? Can you share the insert you use as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the **ItemType** in the **Update.Replace** method:

```
collection.Update(
    Query.EQ("key", item.Key),
    Update.Replace(ItemType, item),
    UpdateFlags.Upsert
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this issues. In my model from C# i mentioned a attribute named "BsonDiscriminator" this one causes the issues in my case.

[for more details](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/apidocs/bson/org/bson/codecs/pojo/annotations/BsonDiscriminator.html)