# How to prevent _t and _v when inserting into MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm utilizing Dictionary. After **.insert()** there are "_t" and "_v". Two posts here talked about [serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199862/how-do-i-prevent-t-field-from-appearing-when-upserting-into-mongodb) converting to [JSON first then BSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786403/dictionarystring-object-to-bsondocument-conversion-omitting-t-field). I'm using MongoDB's driver v2.4.3,

```
mCollection.InsertOne(x);
IMongoCollection<myDoc> mCollection = Db.GetCollection<myDoc>("whatever");
```

If I do JSON-to-BSON, it complains about can't convert BsonDocument to myDoc. Switching to `IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> mCollection = Db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("whatever");` still get _t and _v.

How to avoid _t and _v?

[image]

Here is my code of data type and utilization:

```
public class myObjForDictionary
    {
        //...
    }
    public class myDoc
    {
        // ... some other elements, then Dictionary
        public Dictionary<string, object> myDictionary { get; set; }
    }

    // to instantiate the
    class myClass
    {
        // define MongoDB connection, etc. 
        // instantiate myDoc and populate data
        var x = new myDoc
        {
            //...
            myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "type", "something" },
                { "Vendor", new object[0] },
                { "obj1", //data for myObjForDictionary
                }
            };
        }

    }
```

Comment: Same issue here...

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis what is exactly that you need in this? This issue happens because we try to save Object as a BSON instead Object's JSON as a BSON

Comment: What do you want the result to be?   If not _t and _v, then what should the value be for Vendor and obj1 ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [DictionarySerializationOption](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/1.11/serialization/#dictionaryserializationoptions)... which gives you a couple of different options out of the box to determine how your dictionary gets serialized.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to save some information (`_t`) of what object the deserializer needs to create when deserializing the object, if not it won't know what to create from the BSON.

Alternatively, you could change the `Dictionary<string, object>` to `Dictionary<string, BsonDocument>` and deal with the `BsonDocument`s directly within your code. This will be very similar to how you use `JObject` within `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Answer (score 1):

It also happens when the passed model to mongo is not exactly the type that is defined on the model.

In this case, mongo will add `_t` as it identifies that you expect to read the inheritor's class type, and not the type that is defined on the model.

For example:

```
public class ParentClass { }

public class ChildClass : ParentClass { }

public class ModelToInsert 
{
   public ParentClass property { get; set; }
}

...
// ChildClass is passed instead of ParentClass 
collection.InsertOne(new ModelToInsert { property = new ChildClass() });
```