# Issues with MongoDb storing objects

Tags: c#, mongodb

Trying to store one field in my Entity as an object. The object type is undefined, as it can be used to store different type of objects.

When it gets called, the Web API is receiving it as Dictionary paired values.
Once that inserts into MongoDb, it has these weird _t & _v JsonObject fields.

Can someone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You could probably at least start with identifying which language you are programming in and any framework ( if any ) which is being used for the data access. Could be C# could be mongoose. I don't know, because you did not include either tag or any code.

Comment: The language is c# , using the mongo.net driver on the Web API to perform CRUD functions into Mongo.

Comment: They are **required** for serialization/deserialization. See : [How to prevent _t and _v when inserting into MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42943709/2313887). Also please do not post code in comments. There is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55055815/edit) link on your question that you use to add such information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your property a dynamic ExpandoObject rather than "object", it will deserialize properly and you will be able to then insert it into mongodb. The latest Mongo c# driver supports dynamic.

for example

```
public class NotificationDTO
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ExpandoObject CustomData { get; set; }
}
```

To use your strong types as ExpandoObjects in your DTO You can write a simple extension to help you convert your strong types to dynamic, something like this:

```
public static dynamic ToDynamic<T>(this T obj)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();

    foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        var currentValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj);
        expando.Add(propertyInfo.Name, currentValue);
    }
    return expando as ExpandoObject;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hey I managed to solve it myself.

ExpandoObject is what you need to send to Web API. It will ultimately convert into Dictionary